# Dotted borders on table with border-radius

Tags: css

I have a table with rounded corners on the bottom, created with:

```
border-bottom-left-radius:pixel;
```

and same for the right bottom.

When I add:

```
bottom-border-dotted; 
border-bottom-color:white;
```

the dotted white border appears correctly (rounded), but the table bottom reverts back to a rectangle.  I have a solid background color in this table.  When I replace" `bottom-border-dotted`, with `border-bottom-solid`, with the same white color everything is fine.

I just love the dotted border, especially at Christmas.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please format your code? And for this question, a demonstrating example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or something similar would be helpful.

Comment: You might also want to add a few more general tags - #css would be an appropriate one here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some errors in the `CSS`. F.e.: `bottom-border-dotted;` is not valid CSS. You should use `border-bottom: 3px dotted black;` or `border-bottom-style: dotted;`.

Try this example (see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zT2b/))

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border: solid 3px black;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    border-bottom: 3px dotted black;
}
```

**Result**

Above code will create something like this:

[image]